# Resolving dependency conflicts with pyannote audio and whisper

Tags: python, dependencies, onnxruntime, openai-whisper, whisper

As I've posted about before, I'm trying to install and run a package called Gailbot. For the most part it worked, however I'm having some dependency conflicts! I've fixed some, but there are others I'm struggling to fix:

1. Gailbot requires onnxruntime 1.15.1 and pyannote-pipeline2.3, which are incompatible with pyannote audio 3.0.0.
2. Gailbot requires faster-whisper 0.7.1 which is incompatible with whisperx 3.1.1.

Essentially I'm asking if there are more experienced users of these packages that could help identify/find versions of pyannote audio and whisper that are compatible with the versions of other things I mentioned above?

For issue #1: I did try to solve this by installing pyannote audio 2.1.1 (iirc) which was the most recent version I could find before 3.0.0, but that led to a whole host of other dependency conflicts.

For issue #2: I couldn't find other versions of whisper but I'm also really new to all this so that's likely the issue.